# Replacing a ListView by MapView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an `Activity` where I am having a `ListView`, but on click of a `Button`, I want to replace the `ListView` with a MapView.
I've some options to do this, like having `MapView` loaded in the Layout already, but setting it's visibility to `View.GONE` and make it visible only when the user clicks on the button.
Another option would be to use a `removeView()` and `addView(),` however I can't do this as the Layout is LinearLayout and the View should be added in middle of it.(Don't know if there's any method to do it).
Last option is to use `ViewStub`, however I've never used it before.

Which of the above option is best performance-wise and why? Considering the user can switch between `ListView` and `MapView` multiple times.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention `ViewSwitcher`, never used it before too.

Comment: to answer your first question, there is : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that, but I don't think I should be adding and removing Views frequently.

Comment: If you intend switching between the two multiple times, I would add them both to the layout and show/hide the corresponding ones, as this wold be faster.  If you only intend to do it once, then adding/removing may be a better solution.

Comment: Yeah it'd be easier to do, but would it'd be good performance-wise, as the MapView, as well as ListView both are too heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I've come to know these things -
Adding and removing Views would be too bad and prone to crashes.
Setting Visibility is a good option, however, the performance doesn't improve.
Using `ViewStub` is better solution, as the initial loading time is reduced.
Using `ViewFlipper` is also very easy to use solution. It's so easy that I ended up using `ViewFlipper` in my application and there's no major impact on performance.(Main reason was it's easy to added animation in it)

I am trying to use ViewStub in ViewFlipper. I'll let you know when I'll be successful in doing it.

**PS:** The question is still open to answers. Let me know if I made any mistake here.

Comment: I think, we have enough suspense built up by now. Were you had any success using viewstub inside view flipper or viewswitcher?

Comment: It's been 7 years. I forgot what was I trying to achieve, if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make one `LinearLayout` in which there are two widgets `ListView` and `MapView`. In the `onCreate` method of your `Activity` set the visibility of your `ListView` to `Gone` with:

```
    listview.setvisibility(View.GONE);
    mapview.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

methods and then on button click listener put the following code as below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mapview.setvisibility(View.GONE);
listview.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//set adapter of your listview
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not asking how to do it. I am asking about performance, which one is best to implement performance-wise.